# Work in 'source mode' but enable toolbar buttons

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am building a simple forum on my website using CKEditor as a BBCode editor. I managed to make CKEditor output BBCode just fine by following the [example](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/bbcode.html).

However, I do not want to use the 'WYSIWYG' interface. I just want a plain "bbcode source" editor. The WYSIWYG output is not exactly the same as how the output will look on my forum (because I translate the bbcode to html myself and then apply some additional styling) and I don't really like the difference. More importantly, I have a couple "custom bbcode" tags that make no sense outside of my forum and obviously CKEditor doesn't know what to do with them, so I get a mix of bbcode and WYSIWYG output which looks odd.

I can force the CKEditor into 'source mode' by setting the `startupMode` and removing the source button, but when I do that **it disables the entire toolbar**!

I want to work in source mode, but still use the various buttons like **B**, *I*, etc. When such a button is pressed I just want it to insert the [b] [/b] tags for example around the selected text.

This is pretty much how every forum I've ever seen works, but I can't figure out how to configure CKEditor to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's impossible. Most of the plugins require WYSIWYG mode and don't work without it.

However you could try to control the output of the editor and change it according to your needs by adjusting [editor's filter](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter) or [implementing custom data processor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dataProcessor).

Comment: Can you provide some more insight into how filters or data processors might be implemented to achieve the functionality of basic style and html buttons working in source mode?